# Creating asynchronous and parallel process for dynamic types

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a deserialized JSON array which I want to loop through and call some queries and copy some files in OneDrive. I can loop through each manually but I also wanted to see if I could get a task awaitable version setup. I have both written out below but I run into a error for the second method:

```
        var parentJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(ParentJSON);
        var childrenJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(ChildrenJSON);

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            foreach(var childReview in childrenJSON)
            {
                var ParentID = (int)parentJSON.ID;
                var ChildID = (int)childReview.ID;

                var queryResult = connection.QuerySingle(query, new { Parent = ParentID, Child = ChildID });
                var path = Path.Combine(fileDirectory, queryResult.CHILD_PATH);

                DriveItem FolderInfo = await oneDrive.DriveItemInfoAsync(SharedDriveID, path, "path");
                var CopiedDriveItem = await oneDrive.CopyFileAsync(SharedDriveID, path, "path", queryResult.CHILD_FILENAME, FolderInfo.Id);
            }
        }

        var tasks = childrenJSON.Select(async file => {

            var ParentID = (int)parentJSON.ID;
            var ChildID = (int)file.ID;

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                var queryResult = connection.QuerySingle(query, new { Parent = ParentID, Child = ChildID });
                var path = Path.Combine(fileDirectory, queryResult.CHILD_PATH);

                DriveItem FolderInfo = await oneDrive.DriveItemInfoAsync(SharedDriveID, path, "path");
                var CopiedDriveItem = await oneDrive.CopyFileAsync(SharedDriveID, path, "path", queryResult.CHILD_FILENAME, FolderInfo.Id);
            }
        });
```

The error is:

```
CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type.
```

If I were to bind the serialized query results to a model I know I can use this task awaitable approach however using dynamic casting from my deserialized JSON results in this error. How do I get around this? I am not sure how I should cast this and why is it so strict for dynamic types despite you can foreach loop through them.

Comment: I don't know the reason you're getting that, but assuming `ChildrenJSON` is a JSON array, try deserializing it into a `List<dynamic>` rather than just `dynamic` and see if that changes anything.

Comment: I used IEnumerable<dynamic> and it fixed the error however would List be better?

Comment: No, `IEnumerable` is fine.

Comment: List it as an answer and I will select it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Select()` method that you're trying to use is [`Enumberable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select%60). However, the compiler will not use that, since `ChildrenJSON` is `dynamic`. Instead, the compiler assumes that this unknown `dynamic` object will have a `Select()` method at runtime. That error is not specific to using `Select()` - it would happen if you called any method on a `dynamic` with a lambda as an argument. For example, `childrenJSON.Blah(i => {})` would produce the same compiler error.

If `ChildrenJSON` is a JSON array, then deserialize it into `IEnumerable<dynamic>`:

```
var childrenJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<dynamic>>(ChildrenJSON);
```

The when you call `.Select()` it will use `Enumerable.Select`.